# how to format date in elasticsearch 7.6.2

Tags: date-formatting, elasticsearch-7

the DATETIME_FORMAT function seems to be removed in 7.6.2,so how to format the date in essql. I want to filter today's data by the sql and  there is a wrong sql

`SELECT * from table WHERE date > DATETIME_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYYMMDD')`

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jelly Zero please find attached link for your reference, this might help for your query.
[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html]

Let me know if you have any issues

Comment: Sorry to reply you so late. I want to use date-fromat in 
 essql, like this [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-functions-datetime.html]